# Why the behaviour of a Random variable differs when defining as static or not-static?

Tags: c#, wpf, random, static-variables

my question is: why the behaviour the variable "_random" changes when it is defined as static / non-static?

==> when static defined: _random.nextDouble() returns really random values.

==> when not: _random.nextDouble() returns almost the same values.

```
class Shape   
{  
    protected Canvas _canvas;
    protected UIElement _element;
    static Random _random = new Random();

    public Shape(Canvas canvas)
    {
        _canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        double val1 = _canvas.ActualWidth * _random.NextDouble();
        double val2 = _canvas.ActualHeight * _random.NextDouble();
        _element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, val1);
        _element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, val2);
        _canvas.Children.Add(_element);
    }

}


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Shape s1 = new Circle(MemoCanvas);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Shape shape1 = new Circle(MemoCanvas);
            shape1.Draw();

            Shape shape2 = new Square(MemoCanvas);
            shape2.Draw();

        }
    }
}
```

Note: somehow I couldnt format my post, sorry.

Best Regards

Comment: Take a look at the Remarks on the [Random ctor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx) page: *The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are creating a new `Random` object for each `Shape` object that you create in the loop, which means that they will produce the same series of random numbers as the random generator is seeded from the system clock.

This always happens if you create new `Random` instances too close in time.

When you define the `_random` field as `static`, only one single `Random` object will be created and used across all instances of the `Shape` class.

Comment: Just be careful with `static` as `Random` isn't thread-safe. Just another gotcha to look out for.